# Filtering a list of Object with APEX

Tags: apex

I am trying to filter a list of object in Apex with Clean code.
Look for it on internet but did not find what I was looking for.

Let say I created a list:

```
List<Market__c> RelevantMarketData = [select Id, name from Market__c where country_link__r.Id IN :RelevantCountryList] ;
```

Now I would like to filter that list to select ONLY the market that have a Name: 'France'

I could do a for loop and if.. so for item in RelevantMarketData if item.Name = 'France'
Then push it to a new list.

Is there a function to do it in a cleaner and most efficient way?

Thx you

Comment: I don't think there's much more you can do if you need to filter out the french markets based on an original list of records. If you don't need to store the RelevantMarketData you could use a SOQL for-loop or/and apply the market name filter on the initial query.

Comment: Yes But I need to filter it for many purposes not only French. .. I do not want to make multiple SOQL query

Comment: Then if you need the unfiltered list for additional purposes your approach is the correct one.

Comment: we dont have lamdas, streams, filter in Apex. You have to use ugly for loops.

Comment: If you need to filter for multiple Names, you can build a `Map<String, List<Market__c>>`. This way you need only one loop over the whole list, then everytime you need to get the list of markets for a specific country you can get it from the map. `Map.get(key)` runs in constant time.

Comment: You can leverage an open source library to provide abstractions like filters and lambdas, such as [this one](https://github.com/ipavlic/apex-lambda) or [this one](https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-collections). Obviously some form of looping is happening somewhere, but it is at least more obvious what you are doing and the code doesn't directly loop.

Comment: another library is [this one](https://github.com/bluewolf-beyond/selector)